# Accessing enum Members in C

Tags: c, struct, enums

I have a function that is of type of a struct, which contains some integers and a reference to an enum, as such:

```
typedef struct Test {
    Error e;
    int temp;
    int value;
}Test;
```

Where the enum is:

```
typedef enum Error {
    IOError,
    ExternalError,
    ElseError,
}Error;
```

And say I have a function that wants to return an error (Of an enum of the 3), depending on if something happens.

Where the function is of type Test (I can't change any types or values passed in),

Why can't I return the error like this? How would I go about returning it (I can't change the struct definitions nor the function prototypes).

```
Test errorFunc() {

    return Test->e->IOError; //gives an error
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why have you tagged this C++?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to, just do this

```
Error
errorFunc() 
{
    return IOError;
}
```

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) there are no *static* struct members, nor `namespace`s so you just use the `enum` *value*<sup>1</sup> directly.

Also, in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you woudn't use the `->` indirection operator for that instead you do something like this

```
class Test
{
public:
    enum Error
    {
        IOError
    };
};

And then you can have

Test::Error
errorFunc()
{
    return Test::IOError;
}
```

Which is apparently why you are confused.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>An `enum` is not a `struct` so technically it has no *members*</sub>

Comment: `You don't need to because this is not c++, just do this` you neither do in c++

Comment: In c++ you can have `class Test{ enum Error {IOError, ...};};` and then `Test::Error errorFunc() { return Test::IOError; }` which seems to be the reason of the confusion.

Comment: Yeah this is in C, sorry for tagging c++

Answer (score 1):

In C, you would code:

```
Test errorFunc() {
    return IOError;
}
```

This is C, everything is in the global namespace, there are no "strong" enums and enum "members" are basically "weakly typed integer constants". So, accessing a "data member" of an enum makes no sense. Just use the constant.

Compiler will check if the constant used is of the type you return and complain if it isn't. How much it will complain depends on the compiler, as enums are a little strange weak type concent (Stroustrup once called them "curiously half baked concept").