# Error passing union with enum on function

Tags: c

I am getting this error and dont know what to do :

error: request for member 'Number' in something not a structure or union
22 |     if(answer==user.choice.Number)

The program chould check if the user input is equal to one of the enum elements and then print the number or the string in the union

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum{
    Number = 1,
    String = 2,
}eenum;


union data{
    int x;
    char str[10];
    eenum choice;
};


void display(union data user)
{
    int answer;
    puts("Enter1 or 2:");
    scanf("%d",&answer);
    if(answer==user.choice.Number)
    {
    user.x = 5;
    printf("%d\n",user.x);
    }
    else{
   strcpy(user.str,"hello");
     printf("%s\n",user.str);
    }
}

int main() {
union data user;
display(user);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing enum Members in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34828106/accessing-enum-members-in-c)

Comment: @RuudHelderman no i dont understand the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums treated as global identifiers. You should access your `enum` like that:

```c
enum input_type {
  NUMBER = 1,
  STRING = 2
}

...

if (answer == NUMBER) { ...
```

And for improve your understandings about enum, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226185/c-using-enum-inside-struct).